# Создание массива объектов в R

Tags: массивы, объекты, r

Как создать массив своих объектов в R ?
 
Допустим, у меня есть класс:

```
setClass("Runner",
         representation(name="character",time="numeric",place="numeric"),
         prototype(time=0,place=0)
         )
    a = readline("Enter amount of person")
foo = list()
for(i in 1:a){
    u = readline("Name")
    t = readline("Time")
    t = as.integer(t)
    tmp = new ("Runner",
                name = u,
                time = t
               )
    foo[i]=tmp
}
```

`foo` - мой массив объектов. Но при компиляции ошибка:

> In `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = ) :
>     implicit list embedding of S4 objects is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно заменить `[]` на `[[]]` при присвоении нового элемента списка. Также размер списка лучше определить заранее.

Обратите внимание, что результат работы `readline` - всегда `character`, в то время как в коде подразумевается, что это число.

```
setClass("Runner",
         representation(name="character",time="numeric",place="numeric"),
         prototype(time=0,place=0)
)
a = as.numeric(readline("Enter amount of person:"))
foo = vector("list", a)
for(i in 1:a) {
    u = readline("Name")
    t = readline("Time")
    t = as.integer(t)
    tmp = new ("Runner",
               name = u,
               time = t
    )
    foo[[i]] = tmp
}
```